# C# clickonce Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, clickonce

when i use http to publish the sw, everything will work fine, just one click on the button of "install", the sw will run automatically the installation process .
but when i use https to publish, it can only create the install page, when i click the install button, it will show the error:

> - Downloading https://server/sw.application did not succeed.
>         + The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
>         + The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

first i thought it maybe the problem of signing, i use VS create one test certificate, and install this certificate into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. 
after that, the error still there